# Apagar um flash[:success] alguns segundos após ser mostrado ao usuario?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tenho um formulario de cadastro utilizando Rails, aonde após o usuário concluir o cadastro, ele é redirecionado para a página de login juntamente com um `flash[:success]` que mostra uma mensagem de boas vindas.

Minha duvida é se teria alguma forma no próprio rails fazer com que esse `flash[:success]` desapareça apos x segundos?

Ou sera melhor fazer isso usando javascript?

Segue codigo:

UsersController

```
def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      flash[:success]= "Cadastro realizado com sucesso!"
      redirect_to sign_in_path
    else
      render action: :new
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `Ruby` não vai te dar acesso a esse tipo de controle, você precisa usar Javascript, um exemplo:
HTML:

```
<div id="flash">Flash[:success]</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
//executa a função depois de 5 segundos
window.setTimeout( fade_flash, 5000 );
function fade_flash() {
    $("#flash").fadeOut(1000); //o fadeOut dura 1 segundo
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6subufnv/1/)